# Change CMake arguments for NetBeans project

Tags: c++, netbeans, cmake

I'd like to know how could I change CMake arguments after creating a Netbeans project.

As for now (8.0.2) I can tune CMake arguments via the "C/C++ Application from existing sources" wizard. It allows to pass arguments to "configure script" and it runs cmake if I point "script" to CMakeLists.txt

But I can't find a way to change these arguments from an existing project.
Also, is there a CMake variable viewer in Netbeans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cmake-gui` application. It's not a part of Netbeans, of course, but it does the job - displays current variables and lets you modify them and then reconfigure the cache. It will keep all settings that were set by Netbeans during initial configuration, except the case when change your compiler.

Also, there is awesome [KDevelop IDE](https://www.kdevelop.org/), which has CMake cache editor integrated in it.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, KDevelop lacks remote building & debugging support